# Using fetch_assoc to iterate through MYSQL results with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I'm attempting to use the "fetch_assoc" functionality in order to collect all the "blog" fields of all the rows in my table.

At the moment, it sort of works; it collects the contents of the **first** "blog" field in the **first** row, however for every other row it collects the same data from the first row.

So, for example, this is the code I'm using:

```
$connection = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db);

$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `Blogs`");
$blogs = array();
$max = sizeof($blogs);
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $blogs[] = $row['Blog_Contents'];
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $max; $x++) {
      echo ("<div align=center> <div class=container> <div class='well well-lg wow bounceIn' data-wow-delay='.1s'>" . $blogs[$x] . "</div> </div> </div>");
    } 
}
```

There are four rows in the table as of now- so row **one** would have:

```
Hello this is blog number 1 of the test scheme
```

Row **two** would have:

```
Hello this is blog number 2 of the test scheme
```

And the same for 3 and 4, with the number in the blog increasing with it's index.

At the moment, my code is producing the following result:

```
Hello this is blog number 1 of the test scheme
Hello this is blog number 1 of the test scheme
Hello this is blog number 1 of the test scheme
Hello this is blog number 1 of the test scheme
```

Could anyone please tell me why my code isn't reading the other Blog_Contents?

And maybe tell me how to rectify the code?

Sorry if I wasn't explaining it very well; I have tried to research this as much as I could but couldn't find what I needed.
Thanks in advance,

Sparkhead95

Comment: `$blogs = array(); $max = sizeof($blogs);` that always sets $max=0 and therefore your for-loop will always have only one interation. Wht are you trying to achieve by this construct?

Comment: @VolkerK Ah of course, I didn't notice I'd done that. I was trying to set blogs[] to be the same size as the amount of rows in the table

Comment: the for loop should not be in the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @VolkerK for pointing it out- I had this in my code:

```
$blogs = array(); $max = sizeof($blogs);
```

So my $max variable was always 0.

I changed my code to this:

```
$connection = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db);

$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `Blogs`");
$blogs = array();

while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $blogs[] = $row['Blog_Contents'];
}
$max = sizeof($blogs);
for ($x = 0; $x <= $max; $x++) {
    echo ("<div align=center> <div class=container> <div class='well well-lg wow bounceIn' data-wow-delay='." . $x . "s'>" . $blogs[$x] . "</div> </div> </div>");
}
```

And now it works.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the value of $max within the while loop

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `Blogs`");
$blogs = array();

while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $blogs[] = $row['Blog_Contents'];
    $max = sizeof($blogs);
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $max; $x++) {
      echo ("<div align=center> <div class=container> <div class='well well-lg wow bounceIn' data-wow-delay='.1s'>" . $blogs[$x] . "</div> </div> </div>");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thankyou- I figured it out. Posted my solution here too.